# Counting consecutive days including weekends SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an sql query that counts consecutive days but i need it to count weekends to. For example, if someone has a friday and a monday off i need this to count as 2 consecutive days if that makes sense.

tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Absence(
Date Date,
Code varchar(10),
Name varchar(10),
Type varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Absence (Date, Code, Name, Type)
VALUES ('01-10-18', 'S', 'Sam', 'Sick'),
('01-11-18','S', 'Sam', 'Sick'),
('01-12-18','S', 'Sam', 'Sick'),
('01-21-18','S', 'Sam', 'Sick'),
('01-26-18','S', 'Sam', 'Sick'),
('01-27-18','S', 'Sam', 'Sick'),
('02-12-18','S', 'Sam', 'Holiday'),
('02-13-18','S', 'Sam', 'Holiday'),
('02-18-18','S', 'Sam', 'Holiday'),
('02-25-18','S', 'Sam', 'Holiday'),
('02-10-18','S', 'Sam', 'Holiday'),
('02-13-18','F', 'Fred', 'Sick'),
('02-14-18','F', 'Fred', 'Sick'),
('03-09-18','F', 'Fred', 'Sick'),
('03-12-18','F', 'Fred', 'Sick'),
('02-28-18','F', 'Fred', 'Sick');
```

I have this code:

```
select name, min(date), max(date), count(*) as numdays, type
from (select a.*,
         row_number() over (partition by name, type order by date) as 
seqnum_ct
  from absence a
 ) a
group by name, type, dateadd(day, -seqnum_ct, date);
```

And it produces this result:

```
| name |            |            | numdays |    type |
|------|------------|------------|---------|---------|
| Fred | 2018-02-13 | 2018-02-14 |       2 |    Sick |
| Fred | 2018-02-28 | 2018-02-28 |       1 |    Sick |
| Fred | 2018-03-09 | 2018-03-09 |       1 |    Sick |
| Fred | 2018-03-12 | 2018-03-12 |       1 |    Sick |
|  Sam | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-10 |       1 | Holiday |
|  Sam | 2018-02-12 | 2018-02-13 |       2 | Holiday |
|  Sam | 2018-02-18 | 2018-02-18 |       1 | Holiday |
|  Sam | 2018-02-25 | 2018-02-25 |       1 | Holiday |
|  Sam | 2018-01-10 | 2018-01-12 |       3 |    Sick |
|  Sam | 2018-01-21 | 2018-01-21 |       1 |    Sick |
|  Sam | 2018-01-26 | 2018-01-27 |       2 |    Sick |
```

If you look at these lines

```
('03-09-18','F', 'Fred', 'Sick'),
('03-12-18','F', 'Fred', 'Sick'),
```

This should equal 1 consecutive period even though it is a Friday and a Monday if this make sense. How can i edit this code so that it includes weekends to?

Thanks

SQL fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1de27/1

Comment: How is that different from [your previous question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297947/counting-consecutive-days-sql-server)

Comment: @ZoharPeled previous one doesn't include weekends but i need it to

Comment: Is your goal to count sick/holiday days? If so, who cares if you have 1+1 or 2?

Comment: i just need advice on how i can make sure weekends are included in my code too if thats possible

Comment: @RyanGadsdon  Feels like you are using SE as a coding service rather than ask a question so you can code.  From you profile you are a SQL developer.  You should be able to figure this stuff out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name, min(date), max(date), count(*) as numdays, type
from (
    select date, code, name, type, seqnum_ct + sum(weekend) over (partition by name, type order by date) seqnum_ct
    from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, type order by date) as seqnum_ct,
             case when datepart(weekday, [date]) = 2 and 
                       datepart(weekday, lag([date]) over (partition by name, type order by date)) = 6 then 2 else 0 end [weekend]
      from #absence a
     ) a
 ) a
group by name, type, dateadd(day, -seqnum_ct, date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a running sum to create groups to handle weekends. All you need to check is the current row's weekday is 2 (for Monday) and the previous row's is 6 (for Friday), for a given name,type in date order.

```
select name, min(date), max(date), count(*) as numdays, type
from (select a.*,sum(col) over(partition by Name,type order by [Date]) as grp
      from (select a.*,
            case when datediff(day,lag([Date]) over(partition by Name,type order by [Date]),[Date])=1 or
            (datepart(weekday,[Date])=2 and datepart(weekday,lag([Date]) over(partition by Name,type order by [Date]))=6)
            then 0 else 1 end as col
            from absence a
           ) a
     ) a
group by name, type, grp
```